# Why does kubernetes keep reverting my replica spec?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have one cluster in GKE with 3 machines and three workloads/deployments:

```
└─[$] <> kubectl get deployments                              
NAME              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
workload-a        1/1     1            1           4d22h
workload-b        5/5     5            5           70d
workload-c        1/1     1            1           2y29d
```

My cluster doesn't have the resources to handle 5 pods of workload-b running at the same time. I would like workload-b to have only one replica:

```
└─[$] <> kubectl scale deployment workload-b --replicas 1
deployment.extensions/workload-b scaled
└─[$] <> kubectl get deployments                              
NAME              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
workload-a        1/1     1            1           4d22h
workload-b        1/1     1            1           70d
workload-c        1/1     1            1           2y29d
```

However, after a few seconds, GKE/kubernetes seems to revert these wishes:

```
└─[$] <> kubectl get deployments                              
NAME              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
workload-a        1/1     1            1           4d22h
workload-b        5/5     5            5           70d
workload-c        1/1     1            1           2y29d
```

Why is this happening, and how can I keep workload-b at 1 replica?

Comment: What is your gke version? Do you have `spec.replicas` set in your workload-b?

Comment: 1.15.12-gke.20. `spec.replicas` was the way I was initially setting it just by editing the yaml and then the yaml would revert, but it seemed to me that `kubectl scale ...` basically just did the same thing, and it would change the `spec.replicas` value (temporarily, and then it would change back).

Comment: Could you check if there is configuration of [PodDisruptionBudget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) or [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) for this workload? Use command `kubectl get hpa` and `kubectl get poddisruptionbudgets`.

Comment: PodDisruptionBudget in particular looks suspect. After a day or so, the nodes did move down to 1, so it's possible I simply reached the number of disruptions and gke was slowing down the shutdowns or something. For simplicity, we've switched over to compute engine, so I'm not going to keep putting more effort into figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

I was also encountering same problem, for me it was due to HPA but as answered in comments PDB can also be the reason here.